# How to send email via smtp using VB.NET 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I need to send an email via SMTP, I have my SMTP in a Linux Centos Server, and I created the software to send emails with VB.NET 2010.

After using the `namespace` : `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`, I receive an exception :

```
Mailbox name not allowed.
The server response was: sorry, that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts (#5.7.1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an error from the server you're attempting to send the email to; it has nothing to do with your code.  The server you're trying to send the email too probably isn't authoritative for the mail domain you're sending to.

Answer (score 1):

To get free code for sending mails through smtp, visit the below mentioned site:

http://bitsbyta.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-send-emails-through-smtp-vbnet.html

for more tutorials on vb.net,c#.net, C++ and java visit:

http://www.bitsbyta.blogspot.com/